# Theme translation not working

Tags: themes, translation

A few months ago I bought theme from gorillatheme and tried to translate it to my native language which isn't English. Didn't work in any way. Asked from gorillatheme no answer from them, that was 2 months ago. Their support is beyond zero. It is what it is. But i have still problem, no matter how I try it won't take my translation.
I made a child theme and put the following code in function.php:

```
function my_translation() { 
  load_child_theme_textdomain( 'language', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_translation' );
```

Then found this:

```
function my_child_theme_setup() {
  load_theme_textdomain( 'automotive', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages/automotive' );
  load_child_theme_textdomain( 'auto', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_setup' );
```

Still nothing.

Do I need to edit this somehow? Where should my translation should be? childtheme folder or somewhere else? What else do I need to do? I made the child theme with Childify Me plugin.

Thank you in advance!
Best Regards

Comment: Do translation files for your language even exist in the theme? Adding the lines of code you're trying isn't going to help if there's no translations. It's not an automatic process. Somebody needs to do the translation.

Comment: I have, did with poedit both files .po and .mo files exist. Perhaps not i right place?

Comment: Have you tried placing it in `wp-content/languages/themes/`, as described [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/localization/#using-localizations)?

Comment: Tried, not a single line will be translated. I really dont know what i do wrong?!